# SignalR send server request and return value client

Tags: c#, .net-core, model-view-controller, signalr

I am working with .net core 3,1 SignalR server-client application

How can I call server method with return value from client, which was written in C#?

I don't know how to do this

```
public String GetResponseFromUser(String userId, String request)
{
    // Use requestId to be sure the response is on this request
    var requestId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
    hubContext.Clients.User(userId).Request(requestId, request);

    // Wait for client to send response to the Hub's Response method
    var response = ...?

    return response;
}
```

How can I wait for the client response and use this response in my method outside the hub?